# Cant type in my React from when its used as a nested Component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

When I'm calling a Component in react that contains another that renders a form, I'm not able to type into it for some reason. When I treat it like a function instead of a Component, it works. Why is this happening? Do nested components not have access to its parents state or something? Even when I tried to pass the state elements down as props I get the same behavior.

https://playcode.io/1581684
^ reproducible code

```
import React from 'react';
import Wtf from './wtf.tsx'

export function App(props) {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>Hello. Why is does my form behave like this?</h1>
      <Wtf />
    </div>
  );
}
```

wtf.tsx:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Button, HStack, Input } from "@chakra-ui/react";

export default function Wtf(props:any){
    const [ query, setQuery ] = useState('')
    
    function RenderForms(){
        return(
        <>
        <button type="submit" >Search</button>
        <input onChange={(e)=>setQuery(e.target.value)} value={query} />
        </> 
        )
    }

    return(
      
        <RenderForms />
      
    )

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesting the declaration of components could lead to bugs and it's bad practice according to React.

> always declare component functions at the top level, and don’t nest their definitions

I tried as you said to pass the props down and seems like it's working

```
function RenderForms(props:any){
   return(
     <>
       <button type="submit" >Search</button>
       <input onChange={(e)=>props.setQuery(e.target.value)} value={props.query} />
     </> 
    )
}

export default function Wtf(props:any){
    const [ query, setQuery ] = useState('')

    return (
       <RenderForms query={query} setQuery={setQuery} /> 
    )   
}
```

https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state#different-components-at-the-same-position-reset-state

Comment: I edited in "the declaration of" to your first sentence to clarify what I think you mean. Apologies if I'm presuming too much.

Answer (score 0):

import { useState } from "react";
import { Button, HStack, Input } from "@chakra-ui/react";

export default function Wtf(props:any){

```
function RenderForms(props:any){
    const [ query, setQuery ] = useState('')
    return(
    <>
    <button type="submit" >Search</button>
    <input onChange={(e)=>setQuery(e.target.value)} value={query} />
    </> 
    )
}

return(
  
    <RenderForms />
  
)
```

}

Whenever the state of  component is  changed the reference of function changes due to which the component re-renders. As in this case the state is defined inside the parents component due to which every time the state changes parent and child both components re-renders which focus out you from the input element. So defining the state inside child components will re-renders only child component no the whole tree.